# Guess the disney song from the initials number 3

Tags: music

I will give you the initials of the words in the first verse of a disney song and you have to guess which song.

H A Y D T
I A M C
I I L
Y D Y D W G F A R D Y
W C G O  O T P S T W
I I S
S D Y T M
W
D Y T M
Y

Comment: I acted on a comment by Eutherpy

Comment: Would you like a clue

Comment: No, this is perfect! I think it might take a little while longer which is great :D

Comment: OK. As long as you're happy

Comment: Looks like your missing a letter in the fourth line

Comment: Please upvote if you liked this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the intro conversation before the first verse.  It’s

> A Whole New World from Aladdin!  
>  How are you doing that?
>  It's a magic carpet.
>  I-it's lovely...
>  You don't...you don't wanna go for a ride, do you?
>  We could get out of the palace, see the world
>  Is it safe?
>  Sure, do you trust me?
>  What?
>  Do you trust me?
>  Yes...

Comment: Darn it! I was thinking about that, but didn't clue into the intro conversation! (+1) :D

Comment: Well done tyobrien. That one was tough